# Include a .cpp file using Make

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

I want to include GeometricRecognizer.cpp into run.cpp , I have the solution(below mentioned) for CMake which works, i want to include it in another project which uses make the format of makefile is also given below .How to add the dependency of GeometricRecognizer.cpp using makefile ?

CMake:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(run run.cpp lib/GeometricRecognizer.cpp)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(run)
```

Make :

```
INCS_GTK=-I/usr/include/gtk-2.0 -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/include/atk-1.0 -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 
INCS=-I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/mysql -Iframeworks ${INCS_GTK}
LDLIBS=-lconfig++ -lcxcore -lcv -lGL -lGLU -lglut
```

Comment: Edited , formatting was causing the problem

Comment: Three lines? That's the whole Makefile? I really doubt that.

Comment: That was a small part , here is the whole makefile http://sharetext.org/2on2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line in a CMake file does not include a cpp file in another cpp file:

```
ADD_EXECUTABLE(run a.cpp b.cpp)
```

It creates an executable target called `run` which is the result of compiling `a.cpp` and `b.cpp` and linking those files.

In your Makefile the following lines:

```
MAINCXX=${shell find -name '*.cxx'}
TARGETS=${MAINCXX:%.cxx=%}
```

Are the two important lines which actually setup the executable targets to compile and which source files they are created from. As can be seen in those two lines `MAINCXX` is just a list of all files `*.cxx` in the source tree and `TARGETS` will be the same list just without the `.cxx` part (so if MAINCXX=run.cxx then it will be TARGETS=run.cxx)

Your makefile seems to be heavily designed to support that specific usecase, also the real Make magic happens in the last line of Makefile where it includes another Makefile.

You need to look at the file named `generic.mk` and understand how it is designed. If you just want to add another target you can add the following:

```
 run: run.cpp lib/GeometricRecognizer.cpp
     g++ -o run $(DEFINES) $(INCS) $(WARNINGS) run.cpp lib/GeometricRecognizer.cpp
```

The listing of source files can be replaced by a builtin variable in GNU Make.